# Linear-gradient with transform:skew causes transparent line on every stop in Firefox

Tags: css

I'm having a weird Firefox-only issue where a transparent line appears on every color-stop in the gradient. Does anyone know why this is happening?

### HTML

```
<section class="hero">
  <picture>
    <img src="https://api.lorem.space/image/furniture?w=1500&h=1500" alt="">
  </picture> 
</section>
```

### SCSS

```
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
}

picture {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40rem;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,173,164,1) 0%, rgba(119,205,135,1) 50%, rgba(119,205,135,1) 60%, rgba(119,205,135,1) 75%,  rgba(224,233,110,1) 100%);
    transform: skew(-27deg);
    content: '';
  }
  
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

### Demo

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/rickdoesburg/pen/eYGGjGM)

### Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem on Firefox seems to arise because of the calculations it is having to do to accommodate the skew (one CSS pixel maps to several screen pixels on modern screens so there have to be decisions about how to split things when there is a fraction needed).

This snippet takes a different approach - having the linear-gradient going just from top to bottom over the whole element and then using clip path to show the bit you want.

Obviously you will want to play with the polygon x y coordinates to get what you want, but this approach has an additional advantage that it is more responsive - moving to a smaller viewport does not let the stripe cover a large amount of the underlying image.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .hero {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    picture {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    picture::after {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 173, 164, 1) 0%, rgba(119, 205, 135, 1) 50%, rgba(119, 205, 135, 1) 60%, rgba(119, 205, 135, 1) 75%, rgba(224, 233, 110, 1) 100%);
      content: '';
      margin: 0;
      clip-path: polygon(0 60%, 20% 0, 50% 0, 20% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
    
    picture img {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="hero">
    <picture>
      <img src="https://api.lorem.space/image/furniture?w=1500&h=1500" alt="">
    </picture>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```